# Copiar contenido de un fichero definiendo el final con una busqueda de texto en Linux

Tags: linux

Deseo copiar todas las líneas de un fichero desde el inicio hasta la línea determinada por el patrón deseado en otro fichero. Algo así como un

head -n 1000

Sólo que en vez de 1000 quiero que sea una línea definida por una busqueda como las que defines con grep.

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

puedes usar algo así:

```
head -n  $(grep -n "patron" segundo_archivo.txt | cut -f1 -d: |head -1) texto_a_copiar.txt
```

Comment: Considera explicar el código para tener un mejor concepto o idea de la respuesta que estás entregando